# Modifying GeoServer source code

Tags: geoserver

I use GeoServer 2.18.3.

When I do layers overlaying with third-party map, I want to modify URL request arguments.

Below is a picture:

[image]

I want to modify the red frame content "'TILEMATRIX': gridsetName + ':{z}'" TO "'TILEMATRIX':'{z}'".

How can I do?

I kown GeoServer page using Spring Framework and Wicke. I am not familiar with them.
I have read the [GeoServer Developer Manual](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/), but I feel the document is so simple.

Can you give me some methods or clues?

Comment: that's a javascript demo page - you can copy it and make any changes you need. There is no need to modify GeoServer - Maybe you want to look at how OpenLayyers works?

Comment: Yes,I want to change the demo page,but I had not found the position of this page.I do not know how Openlayers works in detail.Can you tell some hints?Thank you.